# How to reverse the output in text file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, text-files

This is my code for writing input to text file

```
ofstream fout("C:\\det.txt",ios::app);
fout << input << endl;
fout.close();
```

this program is working but when i enter more than one input into it its output is like this

`Output`

```
four
three
two
```

in above output two is my last entry and four is my first entry , but i want it in reverse order , the latest input should appear first like

`Required output`

```
two // latest entry
three // 2nd latest entry
four // 3rd entry
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the contents of the file into a vector, reverse the vector and reinsert the strings back into the file.

```
std::fstream file("C:\\det.txt", std::ios_base::in);

std::vector<std::string> lines;
std::string line;

while (std::getline(file, line))
{
    if (!line.empty())
        lines.push_back(line);
}

file.close();
file.open("C:\\det.txt", std::ios_base::trunc | std::ios_base::out);

std::copy(lines.rbegin(), lines.rend(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(file, "\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the file updated as soon as you enter an input, you need a buffer to store the input somewhere (`std::vector<std::string>` maybe) and then write it to file in reverse order.

Also you can read the whole file and rewrite it using `fout << input << endl << readContent;` each time but it is not a good way because it will be slow modifying the whole file each time input is given.

Comment: Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: @Ahmad Edited a little. You need to remove the file operations and instead you should put `vector.push_back(input);`. Then read the vector in reverse writing it to the file.

Comment: @Ahmad Then you read the file contents and rewrite it appending the content to new input you received.